# Discord py join voice command when no one is in a voice channel

Tags: python, discord.py

I had a question about the join command for discord.py.  I have this join function, which works fine, but I wanted specific detection for situations where a user enters the command while not in a VC.

I have a message for if it joins successfully, and then the other option is if someone enters the command while already in a VC.  I just need an elif for if someone enters the command without being in a voice call.  Not sure how to go about this, any help would be appreciated.

````
  voiceChannel = ctx.author.voice.channel
  voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild = ctx.guild)
  if voice == None:
    await voiceChannel.connect()
    await ctx.send(f"Joined **{voiceChannel}**")\
  
  else:
    await ctx.send("I'm already in a VC")```
````

Answer (score 0):

The error which is given out is an `AttributeError` when the user is not in a channel.

***You have to rebuild your code like this:***

```py
@client.command() / @bot.command() / @commands.command()
async def join(ctx):
    try: # Build in a try
    [Your Code here]
    except AttributeError: # If not in a voice channel 
        return await ctx.send("You have to be in a channel to do that!")
```

- `[Your Code here]` = Just insert your `if` and `else` code with the correct indentation.
- Depending on the method used, you may need to modify the command and add a `self`.